# Using Iframe to load content from another HTML

Tags: html

I need to display content(present in another HTML) in an iframe inside an already present HTML page. The iframe should first check if there is some content in the HTML, and only load if there is, if the source HTML is empty the iframe should not load.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

To check wether the content is present in the iframe use this(it uses jQuery and let the id of iFrame be `iframeid`):

```
   <!--free.htm -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $.get("test.htm", function(){
                if($(this).contents().find("body").length<=0)  
                    $("#iframeid").css("display","none");       
             });
         });
         </script>
       </head>

       <body>
         <iframe src="test.htm" id="iframeid"></iframe>
       </body>
</html>
```

Here are dome links that might be of help to you :

- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/
- http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the problem, that I am having is that I am new to html and jquery, so could you kinda help me a bit further on this. If possible could you contact me on my email.

Comment: I'll just edit the answer to tell you where to add all the stuff

Comment: that would be a great help

Comment: still does not work, I copied the whole code, and if the data is there is the test file, then it shows the data, if i delete the data from inside it, the iframe still loads, but is empty

Comment: Instead of  $("#iframeid").css("visibility", "hidden"); try $("#iframeid").css("display", "none");

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use Javascript for this.

Your parent HTML file:

```
<html>
  <!-- Your parent html file contents -->
  <iframe id="iframe" src="">

  </iframe>

  <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //get your iFrame html file
      $.get("iframe.html", function(data) {
          //check if file not empty
          if(data) {
             $("#iframe").attr("src", "iframe.html");
          } else {
             $("#iframe").css("display", "none");
          } 
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks for the answer.Well, i am new to all this, so if I have the source file named "test.htm" and the final file named "free.htm", so where exactly do I edit the name of the source and the destination files.Thank You again